# Data is not retrieved in DynamoDB table but not in DynamoDBv2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, mqtt, iot, aws-iot

[image]

This is the data I receive which inserts into my dynamodb table perfectly fine as seen in the image below.
[image]
However, I want it to be sorted into multiple columns so I changed the action to DynamoDBv2. Upon doing this, it stopped receiving the data. I tried to create a new table, role, and rule but it still did not receive anything. I tried to change the table back into the normal dynamoDB, and it worked but it saved all data (buttonPress and id) in a single column, which is not what I wanted.

**Current Payload:**
[image]

**SQL Statement:**
[image]

**DescribeTable output:**
[image]

Any input is very well appreciated.

Comment: By DynamoDBv2, presumably you mean [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/dynamodb-v2-rule-action.html). The document indicates that each attribute in the payload is written to a separate column in the DynamoDB database.

Comment: Yes. However it does not receive the payload

Comment: Can you share a sample payload and your tables DescribeTable output?

Comment: @LeeHannigan I edited my post to show the current payload and the DescribeTable output. What I want to happen is to store the buttonPress and id in separate columns. Hope I provided the correct info

Comment: what is your primary key in your DynamoDB Table? It seems like it is the Date. If yes, you need to run something like this in your IoT Rule:
`SELECT Date, buttonPress, is from 'topic'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule should select both the keys from the payload also

`SELECT Date, Time, buttonPress from topic`